# ScrollView not working in Android react native

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview

I want to render a list in a view of specific height with scroll feature, I tried using ScrollView, this works perfect in iOS but the scroll is not working in Android.

```
<ScrollView
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            width: "125%",
            maxHeight: scale(100),
            opacity: 1,
            elevation: 100,
            marginTop: scale(50),
            backgroundColor: themes.snuff,
            borderRadius: scale(12),
          }}
          nestedScrollEnabled
        >
          {listItems.map((item: any, index: number) => {
            return renderItems(item, index);
          })}
        </ScrollView>
```

Above is the code, where renderItems is a function which renders a normal text.

**If I remove position: "absolute" from the style**, the scroll works in android as well, but in my usecase I need the position: "absolute" to render the view at correct position on UI.

Can someone please help here? I tried various solutions that I found on internet, but no luck.

Comment: Try putting the `position`, `width`, and `maxHeight` styles in the `contentContainerStyle` prop instead of `style`.